# White-Space has width? (css)

Tags: css

I am interested, if there is any chance to increase/decrease width of white-space chars inside `<textarea>`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/letter-spacing

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`word-spacing`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#word-spacing):

```css
.triple {
  word-spacing: 200%;
}
.extra-1 {
  word-spacing: 1em;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>Normal space:</dt>
  <dd class="normal">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</dd>
  <dt>Triple space:</dt>
  <dd class="triple">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</dd>
  <dt>Extra 1em space:</dt>
  <dd class="extra-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</dd>
</dl>
```

Percentage values were recently introduced and are not widely supported yet.

Answer (score -1):

Quite interesting, I have found out, that `spacing` especially in `<textarea>` can be solved by `font-family`, which you choose for that textarea.

See in action: https://jsfiddle.net/hz3rv73a/6/